# Download a document from SharePoint with version number

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

I need to be able to download a file out of SharePoint (to send externally) that has the version number in the file name.

Is there any way to do this without custom code? If not, how would I code this?

File in SharePoint -> Specifications.doc
Downloaded file    -> Specifications V99.doc

I use SharePoint 2007, but I am also interested in a 2010 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about as close as I think we can come at this time:

http://spversionindocs.codeplex.com/

It allows you to have a version number field in your document that is automatically updated with the version number from sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible out of the box. As for manual implementation I see two ways:
1) If you can use some external application (or, for example, webpart or page) to do that, just get sharepoint file as binary stream and save it with the name you want.
2) If you need it to look like standard downloading, add a new custom button to document context menu (Ribbon in SP2010) and again do whatever you want with that document when user clicks the button.